Docker container inside github docker container self-hosted runner
I'm attempting to implement unit tests using pytest. To run these tests, I need to set up a PostgreSQL database, execute migrations, and then run the tests. I'm aiming to achieve this setup using Docker containers. However, I'm encountering an issue because I'm using a containerized self-hosted runner. When I run the GitHub Action, I receive the following error: "Container feature is not supported when the runner is already running inside a container." Is there any workaround to achieve what I'm trying to do?
